# Scrolling in Firefox and Chromium

Tags: mouse

I can't scroll fast in Firefox and Chromium (in the rest of the system it's fast enough).

I did some research and found I had to type `about:config` in Firefox and change something there and I can't find the setting I had to change (`mouse.withnokey`).

I use well known HP mouse.

Comment: Just enable "Smooth scrolling" at `about:flags` in Chrome and use this plugin in Firefox — https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yet-another-smooth-scrolling/.

Comment: thanks a lot :) now i can enjoy browsing and also can i give you a tumbs up or something to give you a good rating or something?

Comment: Lars, if @ZDroid posts her or his answer as an actual answer--not a comment--then you can accept that answer, which will help your own reputation as well as ZDroid's.

Comment: @EricLambart Now he can.

Comment: @larsvandenbroeck Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable *Smooth scrolling* at `about:flags` in Chrome and use this plugin in Firefox — https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yet-another-smooth-scrolling/.